# Array stores { sign in db

Tags: php

Hello i am trying to do Push Notifications and i am having problem in storing the data in my db table.

For register_id it stores a **{** sign and i dont know what it means.

Here is my php code

```
print_r('goes into fcm');
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data = $_POST;
    $response['success'] = true; 


    $register1=json_encode($data);  
  
    print_r($register1);

    $register = json_encode($data['registrationId']);
    print_r($register);

    $fcm = array(
        'register_id' => $register['token'],
        'platform' => $data['device']['platform'],
        'version' => $data['device']['version'],
        'uuid' => $data['device']['uuid'],
        'model' => $data['device']['model'],
        'manufacturer' => $data['device']['manufacturer'],
        'app_version' => $data['app_version'],
        'added_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    );
```

and this is what I am getting in response

```
goes into fcm
{"api_signature":"a99411e056601896e1ba69540d9161c4","registrationId":{"token":"dxrB4UaJ4UGijApfxeL0sD:APA91bFPNoqUdHb3w7JjVTbuFwkbM6OcJ7ylmJ-IITbAFr1QGF7q-3l1_yOIj5h-fGYC4wGNjRGSI-po_ILf1XuSskr-NTK7utT5FVcLsBAY0iMv_Qupy5xa62mJlFr9Tv5-b"},"app_version":"1.0.1"}
{"token":"dxrB4UaJ4UGijApfxeL0sD:APA91bFPNoqUdHb3w7JjVTbuFwkbM6OcJ7ylmJ-IITbAFr1QGF7q-3l1_yOIj5h-fGYC4wGNjRGSI-po_ILf1XuSskr-NTK7utT5FVcLsBAY0iMv_Qupy5xa62mJlFr9Tv5-b"}
{"success":true}
```

So, it gets the token from the registrationId array (altought it shouldnt be an array) but it stores a **{** sign in table field. Help please

Comment: What does `var_dump($register['token'])` have? (also not clear why you are debugging with unused JSON result, seems a lot more difficult)

Comment: `$register['token']` does not exist. `$register` is the result of a call to `json_encode()` and is therefore a string. You probably want the original value, `$data['registrationId']['token']`